Как заморозить другой процесс на Python?
в cheat engine есть функция, при использовании которой процесс замораживается, то есть он просто зависает и ничего не будет происходить пока ты не разморозишь его. Так вот как это написать на языке python. Буду благодарен если кто-то скинет готовый код

Достаточно запросить данные от пользователя(input) и все замрет в ожидании

инпут заморозит сам скрипт, а надо замораживать выбранный процесс, например игру

Игра не скрипт? )))  Дополните вопрос подробностями. Приведите ваш код и как вы хотите его "морозить" и по какому событию. Сейчас это гадание на кофейной гуще, что именно, где и как вы хотите реализовать.

Ну по любому да игра скрипт, но попробую объяснить по другому, но могу добавить лишь что мне надо остановить процесс, но не завершить и мне нужна функция, которая будет внедряться в процесс и останавливать его, не надо никаких условий это уже там другое дело

@АндрейКотенко если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от него.
